# Proof ODE do not have solution in Real numbers domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to prove that the following ODE do not have solution in Real numbers domain:
$$
\begin{cases}
\big(y'\big)^2=y-\lvert x\rvert\\[1.2ex]
y(x=0)=0
\end{cases}
$$
I found the complex solution but have trouble in explaining why there is no real solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the ODE into the form $y'(x) = f(x,y)$, then you want to analyse the existence and uniqueness theorem for a 1st Non-Linear Order ODE. (The absolute value should ring alarm bells I think).

This should help: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf 
or this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Answer (score 0):

From the differential equation, $y'(0) = 0$, while you said $y(0)=0$.  From the definition of derivative, 
$\lim_{x \to 0} y(x)/x = 0$.  In particular $y(x) - |x| < 0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to, but not equal to, $0$, and that can't be $(y'(x))^2$  if $y'(x)$ is real.